# How to make ADSF/Puma serve HTML files without the .html extension

Tags: ruby, puma, adsf

I am building a static site without the help of Jekyll or any other known static site builder. When deploying such site to a static site host like GitHub Pages or Netlify, these servers know to load `software.html` when I am accessing `mydomain.com/software` (without the `.html` extension).

Is there a way for me to reproduce this behavior when running a local, Ruby-based web server such as Puma? More specifically, I am using Ruby's [adsf](https://github.com/ddfreyne/adsf) wrapper to launch a Puma server to serve my site locally for development.

My guess is that this should be possible by some rack middleware or rack configuration, I am just unable to identify the proper Google search for it.

I should probably mention that I am not interested in the `directory/index.html` approach, since all web servers I have seen add a trailing slash to the URL in these cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/tommysundstrom/middleman-rack-optional-html might help.

actually the code is simple. add ".html" extention if the path doesn't end with "html".

https://github.com/tommysundstrom/middleman-rack-optional-html/blob/df1e50beca7599f3e47c5b83887573434f3253e3/lib/rack/middleman/optional_html.rb#L50

Comment: Thank you. This seems to do the trick. I am leaving the answer unaccepted for another day to see if someone else had any other suggestion, I will accept it if not. In the meantime, I also opened an [issue on adsf](https://github.com/ddfreyne/adsf/issues/16) suggesting to add this as a built in option.